# Allocating memory for nested linked list + using scanf

Tags: c, list, malloc, scanf

I'm struggling with allocating a memory for my linked list which is embedded in it's parent linked list  - nested structure.

**Structure declaration:**

```
typedef struct parent
{
        int x;  
            struct embed    
            {
                int y; 
                int l; 
                struct embed *next;     
            }EMBED;
        struct parent *next;
}PARENT;
```

**Allocating memory for parent list:**

```
PARENT *head = NULL;
PARENT *temp = (PARENT*)malloc(sizeof(PARENT));
```

What can't I figure out is how can I connect to that embedded list for allocating. Any ideas?

Also when we get to allocating memory and getting connection to that embedded list, I want to use a `scanf` function to store some data into that list but I do not know the connection declaration. How does it work, can someone explain? 
Just so you know what am I working on, it is a school project for searching in a tree - starting from point A, finish at point B when inputs are numbers and in between them is a distance variable. So basically I want to find the shortest way (less calculations = short execution time) from getting to point B.

Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Once the structure is properly defined, you can allocate an embedded list element like so:

```
temp->EMBED.next = malloc(sizeof(struct embed));
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need that inner typedef inside the struct definition. In fact, my GCC doesn't like it. This works:

```
typedef struct parent
{
        int x;
        struct embed
        {
            int y;
            int l;
            struct embed *next;
        } embed;
        struct parent *next;
} PARENT;
```

With this, you can allocate and fill a list with something like this:

```
    PARENT p;
    /* build up a list */
    p.embed.next = NULL;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        struct embed *new = malloc(sizeof *new);
        new->next = p.embed.next;
        printf("enter a number:\n");
        scanf("%d", &new->y);
        p.embed.next = new;
    }
```

Comment: where does the `new` comes from? just an integer variable ?

Comment: It's declared as a pointer in the first line of the loop: ``struct embed *new``. You can move the declaration outside the loop if you like, the ``= malloc(...)`` must remain in the loop to allocate a new block of memory for each list node.